# Firestore returns me null value when I call the get method?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore returns null for value.data ?? How can I solve that?? And also how can I pass document id without custom string and which I put it here. My document id in cloud firestore and uid in authentication are same, can I link uid to get data from firestore??
I am beginner in flutter and firebase.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  User? currentUser;
  dynamic? data;

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = _auth.currentUser;
      
      await users.doc("QWhAkxSEXDfn4HJTdwtO1MFnWgz2").get().then((value) {
        print(value.data());
      });
      if (user != null) {
        currentUser = user;
        print(currentUser?.email);
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print('Failed with error code: ${e.code}');
      print(e.message);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    getCurrentUser();
    super.initState();
  }
```

[image]

Is anything relate to flutter web and firestore ?? But I could able to add data to collection but when reading it returns me null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `users.doc` use `await`, like this:

```
await users.doc("QWhAkxSEXDfn4HJTdwtO1MFnWgz2").get().then((value) {
        print(value.data());
      });
```

And fix your collection reference,

````
instance.collection('users');```

It should be "User" as the name in your firebase.
````

Comment: No it's also return me null value

Comment: Edited my answer, check it out.